# best way to check element combination exist in array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-2020, ecmascript-2021

I have array with some element that I want to check if some element combination exist in array that target element is following by any element of checkingSet, if yes, then return true otherwise, return false. For example,
if inputArray is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and looking for combination is ['a', 'd'] then it should return true because inputArray has both in the right sequence.
if inputArray is ['d', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'] and the combination is ['a', 'd'], then it should be false because inputArray includes both elements but in wrong order
or

```
isExist(['a', 'd']) => true 
isExist(['a', 'a', 'd']) => true
isExist(['e', 'd']) => false
```

I can use Set and while loop
but I am wondering if any more elegant or modern way to do?

```
export function isExist(checkArray): boolean {
  let hasA = false;
  let hasB = false;
  checkingSet = new Set(['b', 'c', 'd'])
  const target = 'a'
  inputArray = [...checkArray]
  while (inputArray && !!inputArray.length) {
    const lastOne = inputArray.pop();
    if (!hasA && !!lastOne) {
      hasA = chekcingSet.has(lastOne);
    }
    if (!hasB && !!lastOne) {
      hasB = lastOne === target;
    }
    if (hasA && hasB) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understood what output you expect. How is it true for a,d when set is b,c,d

Comment: What is `target`? And why is `checkingSet` defined inside the function instead of being passed as an argument?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what your method is actually trying to do.

Comment: Why do you use double exclamation mark (!!)?

Comment: updated,@Snirka need to make sure pop exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check that the array contains `'a'`, and after this `'a'` at least one of `['b', 'c', 'd']` is in the array you can do this. First, get the [index of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) the first `'a'` in the array, then check if [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) value of `['b', 'c', 'd']` is [included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in that array after this start index.

```js
function doesExist(arr) {
  const startPos = arr.indexOf('a')
  if (startPos < 0)
    return false
  return ['b', 'c', 'd'].some(char => arr.includes(char, startPos + 1))
}

console.log(doesExist(['a', 'd']))
console.log(doesExist(['a', 'a', 'd']))
console.log(doesExist(['e', 'd']))
console.log(doesExist(['d', 'a']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general version, it's O(n).

```
function doesDupleExistInOrder([el1, el2], arr) {
    let index = arr.indexOf(el1)
    if (index == -1) return false;
    return arr.includes(el2, index + 1)
}

console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["a", "d"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])); // true
console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["a", "b"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])); // true
console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["d", "e"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])); // true

console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["d", "a"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])); // false
console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["d", "a"], ["a"]));                     // false
console.log(doesDupleExistInOrder(["d", "a"], []));                        // false
```

If you want a specific version then just curry the general function AKA:

```
let doesADExist = arr => doesDupleExistInOrder(["a", "d"], arr);
console.log(doesADExist(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]));  // true
```

Comment: I think if you use `arr.indexOf(el1)` to get the first i (and checking for -1) and then `arr.includes(el2, i+1)` it would be a bit shorter and easier to read

Comment: @A_A, Perhaps, but that requires two loops through the array in the worst case, this requires only one. Also it's only 5 lines, so any reasonable programmer could figure out what this is doing in less than a minute, and it's a faster algorithm.

Comment: I don't think so. From my understanding `indexOf(el1)` would iterate until it finds the element at some index `i`. And `arr.includes(el2, i+1)` would start iterating at position `i+1`. So at worst it should be n steps (and for sure still O(n)). Also these methods could be optimized by the browser, but I'm not sure about that

Comment: Hmm ok, I forgot you could plug in an index for includes. I will edit my post.